# How to end a spoken sentence to page redirection, javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, location, constants, sentence

How can I do a page redirection after the verbal feedback,

```
"const sentence = 'Oh Hello,' + name +'.I am Eve. ....'+name +'= human?!..Ive never seen one of those...What does' +name +' look like?';
responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {rate: 0.5}, {pitch: -2});"
```

Immediately after the entire sentence is completed I need the site to be redirected https://www.google.com/?

I'm thinking that I need to insert this code to get it to work is this;

```
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        location.replace ('http://www.google.com'),
```

But I don't know javascript, at all, so any visual help would be very much appreciated. Here is the current structure of my site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />


<style>

#video {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;



}

</style>

 <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

</style>

<body onload="delayedAlert();">

<script>

var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 3000);
}

function slowAlert() {
 var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
 const audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
 var audio3 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];
  var audio4 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[3];

audio.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('....Hello?');

audio2.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('Something is here.');

audio3.play();
var myvar2;alert('Hello?');

audio4.play();

const name = prompt('What is your name?')

const sentence = 'Oh Hello,' + name +'.I am Eve. ....'+name +'= human?!..Ive never seen one of those...What does' +name +' look like?';
responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {rate: 0.5}, {pitch: -2});
}


</script>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/hellllloooo.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>


 <audio>
 <source src="images/whatisyourname.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>



        <video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" id="video" src="images/secondnew.mp4" width="1300px" height="auto" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;" >
        Video not supported.
         </video>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already stated, there are some options in the *speak* function of this API. But, as we can see in the [documentation](https://responsivevoice.org/api/), you may be using it wrong.

At least, what I got from it is that you need to pass an object as third parameter specifying all the options (not one object for each option, as your sample code shows), like this:

```
responsiveVoice.speak("hello world", "UK English Male", { rate: 0.5, pitch: 1 });
```

And there is an option `onend`, that is a callback that will be called when it finished the sentence (or at least it is stated that the library operates that way). So you could do this:

```
responsiveVoice.speak("hello world", "UK English Male", {
  rate: 0.5,
  pitch: 1,
  onend: function() {
    // Redirect after sentence has been spoke
    location.replace('http://www.google.com');
  }
});
```

And if you need to delay your redirect action, for instance, you can always use something like `setTimeout` to do it after a period of time, like this:

```
responsiveVoice.speak("hello world", "UK English Male", {
  rate: 0.5,
  pitch: 1,
  onend: function() {
    // Redirect 2 seconds after sentence has been spoke
    // (the 2000 is the number of milliseconds to wait)
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.replace('http://www.google.com');
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps! Good luck!

Comment: Pitch can only go from 0 to 2 and can't be negative

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @SethStephens. I haven't read a lot about the allowed values of the parameters, just the signature, as I thought that was the main concern in the original question. And sorry to "duplicate" your answer, but when I started writing the question was unanswered yet.

Answer (score 0):

To add an end callback you need to specify it in the options object, also you must supply all of the options in the same object. The fixed code is

```
const sentence = 'Oh Hello,' + name +'.I am Eve. ....'+name +'= human?!..Ive never seen one of those...What does' +name +' look like?';
responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {
    rate: 0.5,
    pitch: 2, // Your pitch can't be negative (according to the api docs)
    onend: () => {
      // enter code here
      // it will be called after the speaking is over
    }
});
```

Take a look at the [ResponsiveVoice.JS API docs](https://responsivevoice.org/api/) to see anything else.